# How can I prevent myself from being automatically logged out of a cisco nexus switch because of inactivity

Tags: ssh, cisco, cisco-nexus

Is there a way where I can prevent myself from being logged out of a cisco nexus switch/router (or any other cisco device) after a period of inactivity?

I get this message after being kicked off:

```
Inactive timeout reached, logging out.
```

I have the following in ~/.ssh/config (have tried specifying via command line flag as well:

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 120
```

Which does not seem to do the trick as I am still logged out after 10-15 mins. If there is a way to do this, I would need to it via something on the client-side, not in the cisco configuration.

Comment: The switch's inactivity timer only cares about keystrokes... that's why `ServerAliveInterval` doesn't help.  In principle, you could build some kind of [`expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) wrapper for your ssh sessions.  That script needs to be smart enough to send a space / backspace every minute or so...  I'm too lazy to write that myself, but I freely license the idea to whoever answers with a working script.

Comment: SecureCRT and PuTTy both support this type of client-side config.  In PuTTy it's under the 'Connection' configuration heading.  Obviously not Linux related, but similar enough to note for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `exec-timeout` on the line you are using to configure it. The timeout is in minutes and `0` means no timeout.

Example:

```
switch# configure terminal
switch(config)# line vty
switch(config-line)# exec-timeout 0
```

Comment: yes that would work although it would require that I change the config on the switch. Was just wondering if there was anything that I could on the client side to prevent my connection from timing out

Comment: Any solution that involves actually using the connection would prevent it from timing out, since you're hitting the inactivity timer.